# How to get response from wsdl with complex Type using php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

Help me please. I have wsdl with complex type example like this :

```
<WL5G3N0:definitions name="commandModificationiSiska">
  <xsd:complexType name="Input">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dn" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="ptOffer" nillable="true" type="tns:ptOffer"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="ptOffer">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="array" nillable="true" type="tns:array"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="array">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="itemTyp" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="itemCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="itemRefPack" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

actually i have found on try to follow one solution in **[this link](http://leifmadsen.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/consuming-soap-complextype-webservice-with-php)**. In that link is similar with my problem but still not working.

and this is my php script i write in

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$param = new StdClass();

$param->array = new StdClass();

$param->input = new StdClass();

$param->input->dn = "XX2042XXXX";

$param->array->itemTyp = "2";

$param->array->itemcode = "AUTOCON2";

$param->array->itemRefPack = "";

$wsdl_file =  "test.wsdl";

  $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_file,array("trace"=> 1,"exceptions" => 0,"cache_wsdl" => 0));

  print_r($client->commandModificationiSiska($param));

  echo "<br/>================<br/>";

  echo "<p>Request :".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) ."</p>";

  echo "<p>Response:".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."</p>";
```

Maybe someplace had resolved for this problem and can help me in here ..

Comment: Thank's @Anju Vineesh for edit my question. Can you answer that ?

Answer (score 0):

Problems solved. 
Very simple solution. 
Input has separated two parameter :

1. dn
2. ptoffer

   "ptoffer" separated in 3 input parameter was named with "array". "array" have  3 parameter , there are itemCode,itemtyp,itemrefpack. Thats the point.

i just have to do this for get respone from that wsdl file.

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_file,array("trace"=> 1,"exceptions" => 0,"cache_wsdl" => 0));

```
print_r( $client->commandModificationiSiska(array(
                                                "dn" => "1222XXX",
                                                "ptOffer" => array('array' => array("itemTyp" => 2,
                                                                  "itemCode" => "blabla",
                                                                  "itemRefPack" => ""
                                                                  ))
                                                )));
```